# Firefox 12, cannot play a sound file. Specified "type" of "audio/mp3" is not supported

Tags: html, firefox, audio

Here is the HTML:

```
<audio controls="controls" tabindex="0">
    <source type="audio/ogg" src="/Public/audio/ding.ogg"></source>
    <source type="audio/mp3" src="/Public/audio/ding.mp3"></source>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

The player displays just fine in the latest version of Chrome (*18*).

Whereas in Firefox 12, the player flashes on initial page load and just fades out.

Here's are the error messages I see when inspecting via Firebug:

> HTTP "Content-Type" of "application/octet-stream" is not supported. Load of media >resource http://localhost:18214/Public/audio/ding.ogg failed.
>
> Specified "type" of "audio/mp3" is not supported. Load of media resource /Public/audio/ding.mp3 failed.
>
> All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.

How can I play an audio file in Firefox 12?

Comment: @SLaks: That's obvious. What I want to know is why it isn't loading the .ogg file I also put in the `<audio>` element.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831625/html5-audio-not-working-on-firefox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure that your server sends the proper content type for the .ogg file. According to the error your server sent `application/octet-stream` while it should be `application/ogg` (or maybe `audio/ogg`).

Since you are using ASP.MVC3 with IIS7, don't forget to add the MIME type for .ogg files.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

`application/ogg`

After you add that MIME type, IIS will serve your .ogg files correctly and the player will work.

Comment: This is for ASP.Net MVC3. I'll go hunting for how to achieve this and edit the solution into your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Edited in the final piece of the puzzle. Thanks again.