# HTML 5 Audio (Firefox)

Tags: html, audio

I'm somewhat of an HTML 5 newbie. The problem I'm having is with the  tag working in Firefox.

The code I used was:

```
<audio src="Repipe-WebsiteNevada_06-24-08.ogg" controls autoplay>  
  <span class="style19"><a href="Repipe-WebsiteNevada_06-24-08.mp3">
      A message from Repipe Specialists</a></span>
</audio>
```

It works locally, but when I upload and test it. The audio player doesn't show up at all.

This is the page:

http://www.repipespecialists.com/landing/ctc/repipe_specialists_usa_test.html

Can someone help please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the type tag to specify you're using audio/ogg. Something like

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="file.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="file.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
```

(Note how you can list multiple files as fallbacks for different browsers.)

---

After that, you still have to configure your server. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9203835/1180926) in particular may he helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried that. Won't work still in firefox: [link](http://www.repipespecialists.com/landing/ctc/repipe_specialists_usa_test.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with your server side mine type configurations and how the browser interpret different content types of response.

The response content-type of your ogg file is `text/plain`, I guess for some browsers like Chrome, it is able to predict the really content type is ogg but Firefox cannot do that.
As a result, Firefox will fail to load this file as an ogg audio.

Comment: You tried text/plain or you change from text/plain to audio/ogg?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Tryit Editor v1.5</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/tryit.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
color:#000000;
background-color:#ffffff;
margin:4px;
margin-top:0px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="position:relative;width:100%;margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:0px;">
<div style="width:960px;height:94px;position:relative;margin:0px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```