# Why do my .ogg files only play locally?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, dynamic, ogg

I am writing a Chrome Web Application in which I am dynamically creating <audio> tags through Javascript.  Javascript is pulling the names from an object literal. When I run the files locally through Chrome, it works just fine.  Once I load them onto a server, they stop working. The dynamic images work fine, so I'm curious as to why the audio does not.  What could possibly be wrong?  Here is my javascript code:

```
var IG = {
  0: { 'sound': 'chair.ogg', 'link': 'images/chair.png', 'name': 'Chair'}
};

var audio1 = '<audio controls><source src="audio"';
var audio2 = '" type="audio/ogg">Your browser does not support the audio element.       Please upgrade your browser.</audio>';

document.getElementById('quiz').innerHTML += audio1 + IG[order].sound + audio2;
```

UPDATE: If I play the sound file directly, it works fine.  Eg: www.site.com/audio/chair.ogg.  I have also tried using mp3 files with the same result.

Comment: Did you checked that your support these file format?

Comment: You have to make sure your ogg file loade. If you run it locally then its load quite rapidly than server. This is issue

Comment: Is your server actually serving you the file. It may not be configured to serve ogg.

Comment: Has to do with the response headers. Local file works because it doesn't have response headers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831625/html5-audio-not-working-on-firefox/9203835#9203835

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  I simply put a " where I needed to put a /

```
src="audio"';
```

needed to be:

```
src="audio/';
```